# sharepoint 2010 search description

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

A client of mine has 2 web applications, sharing the same content types.
These content types (let's call them "A") are of a base type DocumentSet, and include a Managed Metadata Property "B" (which is a indexed column on WebApp 2 in all libraries).

There's one strange thing going on however. Searching and indexing works fine. But when we search in WebApp 2, it always shows the value of the Managed Metadata Property field "B" in the description. And it's always the wrong one. Whatever the real value is of property B in that documentset, it always shows a certain other value from the taxonomy store.

I tried inspecting every single property and field of the item in Powershell, but could not find any reference to the displayed property value.

My question in this matter is:

1) How on earth could this value be crawled and included in the description if it does not exist in the list item?

2) How can I inspect the crawl database to check what properties it has stored?